# cmd PATH error - \common was unexpected at this time

Tags: batch-file, path, cmd

i am adding a line in a .bat file look like this:

```
path %~dp0;%PATH%
```

But this message is shown:

> \common was unexpected at this time.

Let me show you the path.

```
PATH=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program File
s (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD AP
P\bin\x86_64;c:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin\x86;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windo
ws;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Progr
am Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Sony
\VAIO Startup Setting Tool;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Progra
m Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\P
rogram Files (x86)\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;C:\Program Files\C
alibre2\
```

This is the path. The path i want to add (%~dp0) is:

```
C:\Users\Workspace\Desktop\Files\Programming\GoogleSearch\
```

This is important for me.
Thank you.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You could try `setx` as shown in this answer....

https://serverfault.com/questions/88363/how-do-i-set-the-global-path-environment-in-a-batch-file

Comment: set Durry42IsGenius=isTrue("@Durry42"=="Genius") & if "%Durry42IsGenius%"=="TRUE" echo You are a genius! & rem Output is : You are a genius!

Comment: `setx` is for permanently setting a variable.  The real problem here is the parentheses, which need to be escaped with `^` or you need to wrap the path in quotes.

Answer (score 7):

In this particular case the problematic character is closing parenthesis ' **)** '

Instead of this:

`path %~dp0;%PATH%`

use this:

`path %~dp0;%PATH:)=^)%`

The above syntax will tell DOS to replace all parenthesis ) in the PATH variable with their escaped versions ^)

Answer (score 1):

It seem to be the issue described in [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2524009) article. You probably use command language construction with parentheses in your batch-file.

Answer (score -1):

Related to this [post](https://splogadev.wordpress.com/2012/07/03/common-was-unexpected-at-this-time/) (**tested**)

- Remove `%PATH%`variable in your `set PATH=..` string.
- Like `set PATH=C:\Path\to\file` instead of `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Path\to\file`